# Trouble with sql columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got 2 tables in Database (MS Access) (Fruits and Vegetables). Each of them has fields "Date" and "Value". It is possible to have a few rows with the same date.
How can I output a table which will show for each row  "Date", "Sum of Values for Fruits" and "Sum of Values for Vgetables"? And, for example, if there is no "Value" for "Vegetables" for some "Date", then the empty cell will present?

[Example is on the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJsn4.jpg)

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what data you have in the table and what numbers you want to get?

Comment: @CatalinCislariu doesn't the screen shot give you that? admittedly that should not be a screenshot it should be text in the question but it is there.

Comment: @Fred, Александр Черноусов Still the explanation is not complete or is just me. It would be nice if he can give us a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date,Sum(fValue) as FruitsValue,Sum(vValue) as VegtablesValue
FROM
(
SELECT Date,value as fValue,null as vValue FROM Fruits 
UNION ALL SELECT Date,null as fValue,Value as vValue  FROM Vegetables
) T
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT t.date, SUM(f_val) as f_val, SUM(v_val) AS v_val
FROM (
    SELECT date, value AS f_val, 0 AS v_val FROM Fruits 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, 0, value FROM Vegetables
) t
GROUP BY t.date
```